# Function returning address of local variable error in C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
 char* gen()
 {
     char out[256];
     sprintf(out, ...); // you don't need to know what's in here I don't think

     return out;
 }
```

And I am getting this error when I try to compile:

```
ERROR: function returns address of local variable
```

I've tried having this return `char[]` and `char` with no luck.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, when the function returns the contents of `out` will be destroyed.

Comment: The proper answer depends on the used language. Are you programming in `C` or `C++`? Decide, tag accordingly, and _please_ never use both tags again, it's almost always wrong.

Comment: If `c++` is allowed here, maybe use `std::string`.

Comment: @stefan, in both languages local variables are destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: @vonbrand yes, but that's not the point. The question obviously leads to "how to avoid this? / how to return strings?". The answer to this differs quite a lot in these two languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 5):

Your `char` array variable `out` exists only **inside** the function's body.
When you return from the function, the content of `out` buffer can't be accessed anymore, it's just *local* to the function.

If you want to return some string from your function to the caller, you can *dynamically* allocate that string inside the function (e.g. using `malloc()`) and return a *pointer* to that string to the caller, e.g.

```
char* gen(void)
{   
    char out[256];
    sprintf(out, ...);

/* 
 *   This does NOT work, since "out" is local to the function.
 *
 *   return out;
 */

    /* Dynamically allocate the string */
    char* result = malloc(strlen(out) + 1) /* +1 for terminating NUL */

    /* Deep-copy the string from temporary buffer to return value buffer */
    strcpy(result, out);

    /* Return the pointer to the dynamically allocated buffer */
    return result;
    /* NOTE: The caller must FREE this memory using free(). */
}
```

Another simpler option would be to pass the `out` buffer pointer as a `char*` parameter, along with a buffer size (to avoid buffer overruns).

In this case, your function can directly format the string into the destination buffer passed as parameter:

```
/* Pass destination buffer pointer and buffer size */
void gen(char* out, size_t out_size)
{   
    /* Directly write into caller supplied buffer. 
     * Note: Use a "safe" function like snprintf(), to avoid buffer overruns.
     */
    snprintf(out, out_size, ...);
    ...
}
```

Note that you explicitly stated "C" in your question title, but you added a `[c++]` tag. If you can use C++, the simplest thing to do is to use a string *class* like `std::string` (and let it manage all the string buffer memory allocation/cleanup).

Comment: Rather than using the non-portable, Microsoft-specific function, you could instead use the function defined in the C99 standard, `snprintf`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Thanks for the suggestion. I adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: How would you free the memory after that?  Would it be in the method itself, or afterwards?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams: The function returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated string (using `malloc()`), you use this string at the call site and wherever you need it (outside the function body), and when you don't need it anymore, you can just release the memory calling `free()` on the string pointer (to avoid the so called _dangling references_, you may also want to set the pointer to `NULL` after the call to `free()`).

Answer (score 3):

When you use the following declaration in the function `char out[256];` the space allocated will be freed once the function returns, so it doesn't make sense to return a pointer to the `out` `char` array.

If you want to return a pointer to a string you create in the function you should use [`malloc()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) as in

```
char* out = (char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
```

which allocates space for 256 `char`s but should be freed manually at some point with the [`free()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) function.

Or as suggested in the comment by [Brian Bi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481267/brian-bi) pass a `char *` that points to the string you want to use as an argument to your function.

Comment: I think you mean `sizeof(char)` (or better yet `sizeof *out`) instead of `sizeof(256)`, since you only need size for 256 `char`s, not 256 `int`s.

Comment: @Kninnug Yeah, that's what I actually wanted to write. Thanks!

Comment: the problem with the caller passing in a pointer to a buffer is that you dont know how big it is - an accident waiting to happen

Comment: @pm100 I agree, although you have the same problem by allocating the memory for the buffer in the function, the caller doesn't the size of the returned buffer. You can always provide the size of the buffer as an argument along with the buffer itself or have a `#define BUFSIZE 256` to determine the size, it always depends on how you structure your code and the conventions you want to establish.

Comment: Where would you free the memory after that?  Would it be locally in the method itself, or afterwards?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams Once you no longer need to use the contents of `out` or the allocated memory. Since you are returning the pointer `out` I guess you want to use the values it holds, so the freeing would need to happen afterwards, in the code that calls the `gen()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the function `gen` returns (exits) its local variables (such as `out`) run out of scope and are no longer accessible to the caller. So, when you return `out` you return a pointer to memory that is no longer allocated.

There are two options to 'return' a pointer/buffer from a function:

1. Allocate the buffer in the calling function and pass it to `gen`:

   ```
   char out[256];
   gen(out, sizeof out);
   ```

   it is common to also provide the size of the buffer you pass in, since the called function cannot know this. This means that you have to change the declaration of gen to:

   ```
   void gen(char * out, size_t size){
   ```

   You could also hard-code the size of the incoming buffer to 256 (since you have it hard-coded in your `gen` function right now):

   ```
   void gen(char out[256]){
   ```

   That means you *must* provide a variable of type `char[256]` to `gen` (and no other pointers or arrays). But it does allow you to do `sizeof out` *inside* `gen`.
2. Allocate the buffer dynamically inside the function:

   ```
   char * out = malloc(256 * sizeof *out);
   // ...
   return out;
   ```

   this has as advantage that the declaration of `gen` does not change. But it does mean that the calling function has to `free` the returned buffer when its done with it.