# Can we return value which is non pointer to the pointer function

Tags: c

```
 char* xpx(char* src) 
 {  
      char result[sizeof(src)];  

      strcpy(result,src);  

      return result;

 }
```

There are 2 bugs in the above code.
1) strcpy is passing the src as parameters but it is not legal as str 
is a pointer.

I could not able to find the another one. Could you help me?

Comment: But `strcpy` *does* take a pointer.

Comment: You missed both bugs. Passing `src` as the second parameter to `strcpy` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you please correct me then?

Comment: How many bytes is sizeof(src)?

Comment: I think it's your homework, and you need to do it. Or talk to one of the teacher's assistants to get some help. Or hire a tutor.

Comment: Tip: run this function on paper, using square-ruled paper (the type you see in mathematics schoolwork exercise books) to illustrate the state of the stack. Consider what happens to the *values* of `result` when the function returns.

Comment: @user3386109 it is not the homework. It is from the sample exam which I am trying to solve it. It is fine if you can give me some hint.

Comment: My hint is that the other comments have already mentioned both bugs.

Comment: Specifically, please see [finding length of array inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590226/c-finding-length-of-array-inside-a-function), and see [Function returning address of local variable error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c)

Comment: How do you tell the size of a string?  What happens when you return local memory?  Pray that `src` is actually a string so that using extremely unsafe `strcpy()` won't buffer overflow.  `src` is unmodified, perhaps we should tell the compiler about this.  Hell, look at warnings.

Comment: main bug is that it returns the address of a local variable. second bug is sizeof(src) - that gives you the size of a pointer on your platform, not useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) docs:

> ```
> char *strcpy( char *restrict dest, const char *restrict src );
> ```
>
> Copies the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`, including
>   the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is
>   pointed to by dest.  The behavior is undefined if the `dest` array is
>   not large enough. [...] (important but not relevant to the question so
>   omitted part)

So `strcpy` does take 2 pointers. That's fine. It's not a bug.

To find the bug pay attention to (and think about it, it's logical): `dest` array must be large enough. What does "large enough" mean here? Well since the functions copies the string from `src`, including null terminator to `dest` it means `dest` must be at least the length of the string in `src` + 1 for the null terminator. That means `strlen(src) + 1`.

`sizeof(src)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)` which is the size of a char pointer on the platform. The size of the pointer. Not what you want.

The next error is that the functions returns the address of an automatic storage object, aka the `result` array. This means that the array will cease to exist when the function exits and thus the function returns a pointer to an object that is no longer valid. A solution to this would be to use `malloc` to allocate the array. Another is to change the signature of `xpx` to something similar to `strcpy` where the destination array is supplied.

So summing them you need something along this:

```
char* result = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
```

Another bug (yes, technically it's not a bug, but semantically it's a bug in my opinion) is that `src` should be of `const char*` type.

Another source of potential problems and bugs is if the input is not well-behaved, e.g. if `src` is not null-terminated, but it is debatable how much responsibility this function should carry regarding this.

Comment: Note that `char result[strlen(src) + 1];` is only valid on C99 and later standards.

Answer (score 0):

> not legal as `str` is a pointer

Not sure what you mean by that, but passing pointers to functions is perfectly fine.

As for "bugs" in the function, it is hard to say if there are any, given that you have not provided what is the expected behavior of the function. The function is legal C, although quite useless and dangerous to use (and will trigger warnings from common compilers):

1. Do not return addresses to local variables, since they do not exist anymore after your return, so you shall not access them.
2. If you are passing a null-terminated string into a function and you need to get a buffer of its size; then you have to find out its length at runtime using something like [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and then allocate the memory on the heap with [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (or using [VLAs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) on C99 and later).