# Returning arrays with custom function in c not working

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am new to C programming. Take a look at my code & point me where i am doing wrong? Here is my code to create a range function which should return int array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * range(int a, int b);

main()
{
    int *r;
    int j;
    r = range(0,5);
    printf("%d",r[0]); // getting the first one to check array but not working
                       // instead showing segmantation fault
}

int * range(int a, int b) {

    int last[b];
    int i,j;

    for(i=a;i<b;i++){
        last[i] = i;
    }

    return last;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function returning address of local variable error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c)

Comment: int last[b]; what's this?
this is fault

Comment: @aminsaffar `int last[b];` is a VLA (variable length array). It's only a fault if the compiler does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the address of a local array whose lifetime ends with the function.

Change

```
int last[b];
```

to

```
int *last = malloc(sizeof(int) * b);
```

Don't forget to call `free(r);` after the `printf`

Comment: Changed but showing `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]|`

Comment: @RishadTanjim C allows that - even prefers the lack of cast. Are you programming in C?

Comment: wow it works now ! file extension was .cpp changed to .c and now works

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * range(int a, int b);

int main()
{
     int *r;
     int j;
     r = range(0,5);
     printf("%d",r[1]); // Outputs 1
     free(r);
     return 0;
}

int * range(int a, int b){
    int *last = malloc(sizeof(int) * b);
    int i,j;
    for(i=a;i<b;i++){
        last[i] = i;
    }
    return last;
}
```

You can run in Ideone https://ideone.com/OzaYoL

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that the `last` array *ceases to exist* as soon as the `range` function exits, so the pointer being returned is no longer valid.

If you want `range` to set aside the memory for the array as well as initialize its content, then you'll have to allocate the memory dynamically:

```
int *range( int a, int b )
{
  int *last = malloc( sizeof *last * b );
  if ( last )
  {
    for ( size_t i = a; i < b; i++ )
      last[i] = i;
  }
  return last;
}
```

You will need to remember to `free` that memory when you're done with it.

A quick comment - it's not clear to me how you intend `range` to work when it comes to setting values.  If you called `range(3,6)`, you'd get a 6-element array, but you'd only set the values of `last[3]`, `last[4]`, and `last[5]`, leaving `last[0]` through `last[2]` containing indeterminate values.  If that's what you intended, great.  If not, you'll want to re-think this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your function `int * range(int a, int b);` returns address of **local variable**. So in order to correct it you have to *dynamically* allocate memory to `last` .

Try this code :

```
int *last=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*b);
```

This will work.