# C - String returns as NULL

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to make a function which deletes **l** elements, starting from the **k** position. My function returns another set of chars after deleting the chars.
 *String_length* is a function which returns the length of the string.

**Remove Chars**

```
char * remove_chars(char s1[], int k, int l)
{
    int j = 0;
    if(string_length(s1) + 1 < k || string_length(s1) + 1 < l)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        char s2[100];
        for(int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if((i <= k - 1) || (i > k + l - 1 ))
            {

                s2[j] = s1[i];
                ++j;
            }
        }
        s2[j] = '\0';
        return s2;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that after I call the *remove_chars* function in *main*, it returns as *null*, but when I try to print *s2* inside *remove_chars* function, it prints it out just like it was supposed to be.

Comment: Please see [Function returning address of local variable error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c). After the function returns, `s2` is dead, although there might be a ghost.

Comment: `s2` is in the stack frame of `remove_chars`. So, after `remove_chars` returns, `s2` is no longer valid. The quick and dirty solution is to do: `static char s2[100]`. Or, have caller pass down `s2` as a separate arg (e.g. `char * remove_chars(char s2[100], char s1[], int k, int l)`. Or, copy back `s2` into `s1` before returning

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the address of a local variable.

`s2` is an array defined locally.  When you then `return s2`, the array decays to a pointer to the first element.  Once the function returns, `s2` goes out of scope and the memory it used is no longer valid.  Using a pointer to a variable that has gone out of scope unvokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Dynamically allocate memory instead so it will still be valid when the function returns.

```
char *s2 = malloc(strlen(s1)+1);
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory in the calling function when you're done using it.

Comment: Can I assign the returning value to another set of chars in the main function?

Comment: @AdrianCovaci You can assign it to another pointer, or you can copy it to another `char` array via `strcpy`.