# Pointer giving random values after passing into function

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void  deal_queries(int *arr, int limit, int numQueries, int filled) {
    // Write your code here
    for(int i=0;i<filled;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(arr+0));
    }
}
int * read_input(int N,int n){
    //declare dynamic array of size N
    // take input n integers and store them in the array and return pointer to this
    int i;
    int *ptr;
    int array[N];
    ptr=array;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {scanf("%d ",ptr);ptr++;}
    ptr=array;
    return (ptr);
}
int main()
{
    int N,Q,n; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&N,&Q,&n);
    int* arr=read_input(N,n);
    printf("%d ",*(arr+0));
    deal_queries(arr,N,Q,n);
    return 0;
}
```

when I print arr elements in main function I get correct values but if I pass them into deal with queries function I get random values can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe you want `printf("%d ",*(arr+i));` instead of `printf("%d ",*(arr+0));` in the function `deal_queries`?

Comment: Please don't use trailing spaces in your `scanf` formats. That could lead `scanf` to hand waiting for a non-space character to it knows when the spaces ends.

Comment: Please see [Function returning address of local variable error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `array` is local to `read_input`, so its life ends when returing from the function and accessing it after that is illegal.

Instead of that, you should allocate an array on the heap and use that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void  deal_queries(int *arr, int limit, int numQueries, int filled) {
    // Write your code here
    for(int i=0;i<filled;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(arr+0));
    }
}
int * read_input(int N,int n){
    //declare dynamic array of size N
    // take input n integers and store them in the array and return pointer to this
    int i;
    int *ptr;
    int *array=malloc(sizeof(*array)*N); /* allocate an array on the heap */
    if(array==NULL) return NULL; /* check if allocation succeeded */
    ptr=array;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {scanf("%d ",ptr);ptr++;}
    ptr=array;
    return (ptr);
}
int main()
{
    int N,Q,n; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&N,&Q,&n);
    int* arr=read_input(N,n);
    if(arr==NULL) return 1; /* check if allocation succeeded */
    printf("%d ",*(arr+0));
    deal_queries(arr,N,Q,n);
    free(arr); /* free allocated array */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but I had one doubt about calling read_input function call ends , after that if I try to print arr pointer the value of arr in main it gives correct values so that means arr is pointing to addresses of array in read_input

Answer (score 0):

You return the pointer to the local automatic storage variable which is UB as the variable stops existing when the function returns.

```
int array[N];
ptr=array;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{scanf("%d ",ptr);ptr++;}
ptr=array;
return (ptr);
```

You need to make it static (bad way) or dynamically allocate the memory

```
static int array[N];
ptr=array;
```

or better

```
//int array[N];
ptr=malloc(sizeof(*ptr)*N);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `read_input` where you have:

```
int array[N];
ptr=array;
return (ptr);
```

The variable `array` is a ***local*** variable in the function. And the assignment to `ptr` makes it point to the first element of this local array. This pointer will become invalid as soon as the function returns and the life-time of `array` ends.

You need to allocated the array dynamically using `malloc` instead:

```
int *array = malloc(N * sizeof *array);

int *ptr = array;
// Fill array using the ptr variable...

return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointer isn't a problem, it's what it points to. Here is the issue:

```
int * read_input(int N,int n) {
    ...
    int array[N]; // This array is in automatic memory,
    ptr=array;    // so it is valid only inside read_input
    ...
    return (ptr); // you are returning a pointer to it
}
```

In order to do what you want to do you need to use `malloc`:

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

Use another pointer in the loop, or apply indexing to `ptr`, like this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    scanf("%d ", &ptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` bad error prone practice. Use **objects** not *types* in typedef-s.