# Why my fputs doesn't work when the file already contains anything?

Tags: c, file, fputs

I try to add a new line to the already existing file, which already consists some text. I found out that when the file contains something, the program stops working after fputs(stringToAdd, myFile); in function void Save(struct SEED arrayToSave[], int size). However, when I try to write in an empty file, everything works properly. Can you guys please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numberOfItems = 0;
char path[] = "Catalogue.txt";
char text[1000000];

struct SEED {
  int index;
  char type[30];
  char name[60];
  float mass;
  float price;
};

void GetText() {
  FILE* catalogueFile;
  char ch; // temporary char
  int counter = 0;

  catalogueFile = fopen(path, "r");
  while((ch = fgetc(catalogueFile)) != EOF ) {
    text[counter] = ch;
    counter++;
  }
  fclose(catalogueFile);
}

void CalculateNumberOfItems() {
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
    if(text[i] == '\n') numberOfItems++;
  }
}

struct SEED* GetArrayOfStructs() {
  GetText();
  CalculateNumberOfItems();
  FILE* catalogueFile;
  int counter = 0;
  char* arrayOfSubstrings[numberOfItems];
  struct SEED* arrayOfStructs = malloc(numberOfItems * sizeof(arrayOfStructs));
  struct SEED* arrayOfStructsPointer = arrayOfStructs;

  char* token = strtok(text, "\n");
  while( token != NULL ) {
      arrayOfSubstrings[counter] = token;
      token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
      counter++;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
     struct SEED tempStruct;
     sscanf(arrayOfSubstrings[i], "%d %s %s %f %f", &tempStruct.index, tempStruct.type, tempStruct.name, &tempStruct.mass, &tempStruct.price);
     arrayOfStructs[i] = tempStruct;
   }

   return arrayOfStructsPointer;
}

void Save(struct SEED arrayToSave[], int size) {
  FILE* myFile = fopen("Catalogue.txt", "w");
  char fullString[1000000];

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    struct SEED currentStruct = arrayToSave[i];
    char stringToAdd[1000];
    sprintf(stringToAdd, "%d %s %s %f %f\n", currentStruct.index, currentStruct.type, currentStruct.name, currentStruct.mass, currentStruct.price);
    strcat(fullString, stringToAdd);
  }
  printf("%s\n", fullString);
  fputs(fullString, myFile);
  fclose(myFile);
}

void AddNew() {
  struct SEED* oldArrayOfStructs = GetArrayOfStructs(path);
  struct SEED newArrayOfStructs[numberOfItems + 1];
  struct SEED newStruct;
  int newIndex = numberOfItems + 1;
  char newType[30], newName[60];
  float newMass, newPrice;
  char tempChar[200];

  printf("Input type, name, mass and price\nof the new seed whith spaces: ");
  fgets(tempChar, 200, stdin);
  fgets(tempChar, 200, stdin);

  sscanf(tempChar, "%s %s %f %f\\n", newType, newName, &newMass, &newPrice);

  newStruct.index = newIndex;
  strcpy(newStruct.type, newType);
  strcpy(newStruct.name, newName);
  newStruct.mass = newMass;
  newStruct.price = newPrice;

  printf("%d\n", numberOfItems);

  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    newArrayOfStructs[i] = oldArrayOfStructs[i];
  }

  newArrayOfStructs[numberOfItems] = newStruct;

  Save(newArrayOfStructs, numberOfItems + 1);
  printf("\n");
}

void UserInput() {
  char choice;
  int choiceInt, a = 1;

  printf("Add new item - print 1\n");
  printf("\n");

  printf("Input your choice: ");
  choice = getchar();
  choiceInt = choice - '0';
  printf("\n");

  switch(choiceInt) {
    case 1:
      AddNew();
      break;
    default:
      printf("Bye!\n");
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  UserInput();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `return textPointer;` you can't return the address of the local array, which will no longer exist.

Comment: ```getchar()``` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: ... not only that, but the caller would not know where the data ends - you did not terminate a string, or provide a length.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane is that why I can't put anything inside?

Comment: ...and `char text[1000000];` will be likely to break the stack too.

Comment: @Haris it's not NULL

Comment: @WeatherVane but why even with `return textPointer;` I can read what is inside?

Comment: When you leave your theater seat without a reservation, it will still be free for you if no-one else has taken it. You were lucky. Please see [Function returning address of local variable error in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c)

Comment: @WeatheVane wow, alright, I'll try to fix it

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Allocation too small**

Code incorrectly allocates for an array of pointers.

```
// struct SEED* arrayOfStructs = malloc(numberOfItems * sizeof(arrayOfStructs));
struct SEED* arrayOfStructs = malloc(numberOfItems * sizeof arrayOfStructs[0]);
```

**`char` too small to distinguish 257 different responses from `fgetc()`**

```
// char ch; // temporary char
int ch;
...
while((ch = fgetc(catalogueFile)) != EOF ) {
```

**Potential buffer overrun**

Use a *width*.

No point scanning for 2 characters `\` and `n` with `"\\n"`.

```
 // sscanf(tempChar, "%s %s %f %f\\n", newType, newName, &newMass, &newPrice);
 sscanf(tempChar, "%29s %59s %f %f", newType, newName, &newMass, &newPrice);
```

Best to test `sscanf()` result too.

```
if (sscanf(tempChar, "%29s %59s %f %f", newType, newName, &newMass, &newPrice) != 4) {
  TBD_error_code();
}
```

**Overflow risk**

```
// while((ch = fgetc(catalogueFile)) != EOF ) {
while(counter < (sizeof text - 1) && (ch = fgetc(catalogueFile)) != EOF ) {
  text[counter] = ch;
```

**Maybe overflow risk**

```
// sprintf(stringToAdd, "%d %s %s %f %f\n",
snprintf(stringToAdd, sizeof stringToAdd, "%d %s %s %f %f\n",
```